# “asp:Button” não funciona dentro de “mmenu nav “

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou a tentar integrar “jquery.mmenu” num projeto Visual Studio.
Parece que um “asp:Button” não funciona dentro de um “mmenu nav “.
Um "asp:LinkButton" também parece não funcionar em pleno.
Tome-se por exemplo o login dentro do "mmenu nav" como o seguinte:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="test._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login").mmenu({
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <a href="#login">Open login pannel</a><br />
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LoginText="login" LogoutText="logout" LogoutPageUrl="~/" /><br />

            <nav id="login">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server">User:</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server">Password:</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Login Button" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" /><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LoginLinkButton" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="LoginLinkButton_Click">Login LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O código é o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace test
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
            }
        }

        protected void LoginLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O asp:Button não faz postback.
O asp:LinkButton não obtém o login.
Alguma ideia?
Obrigado.

Comment: Quando você clica neles acontece o que? Tem certeza que está clicando neles? não tem nenhum elemento por cima? da um inspecionar e olha isso.

Comment: O asp:Button não faz postback (nada acontece). O asp:LinkButton faz javascript:__doPostBack('LoginLinkButton','') mas não executa o código. Não, não há nenhum elemento por cima.